# How to parse Google Doc

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-docs

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape a Google Doc, the document text is under

[Google Doc HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdmzO.png)

```
<div class="kix-zoomdocumentplugin-outer" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 826px; height: 1066px; left: 79px; top: 4px;">
```

So I am using to reach the element

```
soup.find('div', class_="kix-zoomdocumentplugin-outer")
```

But when I try to print, the result is

```
None
```

I've also tried for loops to reach the element but I've come to the same result

```
agenda = soup.find_all("div", id="docs-editor-container")
for div1 in agenda:
    div1a = div1.find_all("div", id="docs-editor")
for div2 in div1a:
    div2a = div2.find_all("div", id="kix-appview")
for div3 in div2a:
    div3a = div3.find_all("div", class_="kix-appview-editor-container")
for div4 in div3a:
    div4a = div4.find_all("div", class_="kix-appview-editor")
for div5 in div4a:
    div5a = div5.find_all("div", class_="kix-zoomdocumentplugin-outer")

print(div5a)
```

Sorry if I just made a stupid mistake, thank you so much.

Comment: Instead of scraping HTML you should use the [API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/).

Comment: How are you obtaining the HTML you are trying to scrape? Are you copying and pasting it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm wondering if there's a way to parse formatted text from the API. For example, how can I differentiate between a sentence with a font size of 12 and an underlined sentence with a font size of 20